# Windows Live Auth - Get User Profile

Tags: c#, .net, api, oauth-2.0

I created an application in **Microsoft Application Registration Portal**
https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/

On my page, I put a button redirecting the user to the microsoft website. I get the user back after he accepts to dispose the data to my application. So far, nothing wrong.

After the user returns to my page with the code, I make the call to api from microsoft through the url: https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token={code}&oauth_token={code}.
This request is made by library.

The request return to me an error.

```
{
    "error": {
      "code": "request_token_invalid", 
      "message": "The access token isn't valid."
   }
}
```

Library used: https://github.com/titarenko/OAuth2